# Using vector with derived classes

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to use a vector for derived class `Employee` but I got en error:

```
class Company : public Employee, public TesterEmployee, public DeveloperEmployee {
private:
   std::vector<Employee*> _table;
public:
    friend std::vector<Employee*>& operator+=(const Employee* emp) {
        _table.push_back(emp->clone());
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The error is:

> error: `'std::vector<Employee*>& operator+=(const Employee*)'` must have an argument of class or enumerated type

Comment: The code, format it properly. Thanks.

Comment: Just a comment, a company can contain employees, but it doesn't make sense for it to inherit from them. Different types of employees may inherit from a generic employee, and different types of companies might inherit from a generic company type... but this organization is just confusing.

Comment: It also doesn't make any sense for `_table` to be a static member of `Company`. Every company has its own employees.

Comment: As RyanP & FredLarson say, there are many things that don't make much sense with this code. You should probably read a good book on C++. It doesn't look like your problem is with some specific feature at this point.

Comment: There is all kinds of odd going on here. When you declare the vector of employees to be static, you are really making sure that every instance of class company refers to the same vector of employees... was this intentional?

Comment: All that just to really do this?  `#include <vector> class Employee; class Company { private: std::vector<Employee*> employee_list; };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+=` is a binary operator. The function

```
friend std::vector<Employee*>& operator+=(const Employee* emp) {
    _table.push_back(emp->clone());
    return *this;
}
```

defines a non-member function that can take only one argument. Hence, it cannot be used in an expression like:

```
a += b;
```

What you need is:

```
Company& operator+=(const Employee* emp) {
    _table.push_back(emp->clone());
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the other question about the same code (that you deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717107/operator-overloading-in-my-class-with-error):

> **Q** and the problem :
>
> ```
> error: invalid operands of types 'Company*' and 'DeveloperEmployee*' to binary 'operator+'|
> ```
>
> What does it mean?

It means you're trying to write Java/C# code in C++. Don't do that.

- In particular you're abusing OOP for the sake of OOP. A `Company` is-not-a `Employee` (see [Liskov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), and `company + employee` doesn't make sense.
- Lose the `new`.
- Lose the base class.
- Probably lose the `clone` based dynamic value semantics.

Finally, your problem is, you're using `operator+=` which you didn't overload.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02926ba89b9c63a2)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Employee {
    int getID() const { return _id; }

  private:
    int _id = generate_id();

    static int generate_id() {
        static int next = 0;
        return ++next;
    }
};
struct DeveloperEmployee : Employee {
    DeveloperEmployee(std::string const& descr, std::string const& project)
        : _description(descr), _project(project) { }

  private:
    std::string _description;
    std::string _project;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, DeveloperEmployee const& de) {
        return os << "id:" << de.getID() << " descr:'" << de._description << "' project:'" << de._project << "'"; 
    }
};

class Company {
  private:
    std::vector<Employee> _table;
    std::string _des;

  public:
    Company &operator+=(const Employee &emp) {
        _table.push_back(emp);
        return *this;
    }
    void setDescription(std::string des) { _des = des; }
};


int main() {
    Company company;
    DeveloperEmployee a("description", "project");

    int id = a.getID();
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // Developer ID = 2, project = hw5

    company += a;
}
```